# I want to design a form using bootstrap and css3

Tags: html, css

I want to reproduce the design of this page:

[image]

I'm not able to design this page using css3. How can I make a form like this? I'm not able to make the outer red border and add spacing between the fields.

What is the proper way to set the form's background color to red?

Comment: Can you please include the code and styles that you have written so far?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps. Only used Bootstrap 4. It has classes that can help you with the spacing and margins without having to customize CSS.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

button[type="submit"] {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  background-color: #C72027;
}

#submitForm {
  background-color: #F0AD4E;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container col-7 p-3">
  <form>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-5 mb-3">
        <label class="sr-only" for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5 mb-3">
        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control text-uppercase" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5 mb-3">
        <label class="sr-only" for="phone">Phone number</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control text-uppercase" id="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" placeholder="Enter mobile number">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5 mb-3">
        <label class="sr-only" for="location">Location</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" id="location" placeholder="Enter Location">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-3">
        <label class="sr-only" for="programSelect">Program</label>
        <select class="form-control text-uppercase" id="programSelect">
          <option>Select your program</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option>Option 2</option>
          <option>Option 3</option>
          <option>Option 4</option>
          <option>Option 5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <p class="text-white text-uppercase ">Please select your date of birth</p>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-4 mb-3">
        <label class="sr-only" for="day">Day</label>
        <select class="form-control text-uppercase" id="day">
          <option>DD</option>
          <option>01</option>
          <option>02</option>
          <option>03</option>
          <option>04</option>
          <option>05</option>
          <option>06</option>
          <option>07</option>
          <option>08</option>
          <option>09</option>
          <option>10</option>
          <option>11</option>
          <option>12</option>
          <option>13</option>
          <option>14</option>
          <option>15</option>
          <option>16</option>
          <option>17</option>
          <option>18</option>
          <option>19</option>
          <option>20</option>
          <option>21</option>
          <option>22</option>
          <option>23</option>
          <option>24</option>
          <option>25</option>
          <option>26</option>
          <option>27</option>
          <option>28</option>
          <option>29</option>
          <option>30</option>
          <option>31</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-4 mb-3">
        <label class="sr-only" for="month">Month</label>
        <select class="form-control text-uppercase" id="month">
          <option>MM</option>
          <option>01</option>
          <option>02</option>
          <option>03</option>
          <option>04</option>
          <option>05</option>
          <option>06</option>
          <option>07</option>
          <option>08</option>
          <option>09</option>
          <option>10</option>
          <option>11</option>
          <option>12</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-4 mb-3">
        <label class="sr-only" for="year">Year</label>
        <select class="form-control text-uppercase" id="day">
          <option>YYYY</option>
          <option>2018</option>
          <option>2017</option>
          <option>2016</option>
          <option>2015</option>
          <option>2014</option>
          <option>2013</option>
          <option>2012</option>
          <option>2011</option>
          <option>2010</option>
          <option>2009</option>
          <option>2008</option>
          <option>2007</option>
          <option>2006</option>
          <option>2005</option>
          <option>2004</option>
          <option>2003</option>
          <option>2002</option>
          <option>2001</option>
          <option>2000</option>
          <option>1999</option>
          <option>1998</option>
          <option>1997</option>
          <option>1996</option>
          <option>1995</option>
          <option>1994</option>
          <option>1993</option>
          <option>1992</option>
          <option>1991</option>
          <option>1990</option>
          <option>1989</option>
          <option>1988</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check pl-4 mb-3">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="allowCheck">
        <label class="form-check-label text-white" for="allowCheck">I allow NMIMS Distance Learning to contact me to provide details</label>
      </div>
      <button id="submitForm" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning mb-3 text-uppercase text-white">Send Enquiry</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an sample form for you on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/218452/)

I used a form from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/) and wrapped in a div. Then I used `background-color: red;` to style this div. Is not exactly what you want but is a starting point to create a form with bootstrap.